# Change Connections for SQL Server Management Studio solution file

Tags: sql-server-2014

In SSMS solution file, I have a lot of files that have different connection from the server. I want to change these connections in in ssmssln file. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to change the connection for some query files to another connections in the project.

You can change the .ssmssqlproj file under the solution folder via any editor.

Please Change the FileNode under Queries LogicalFolder tag. For example: please change the connection name like the hostname\instancename in the below.

```
<FileNode Name="SQLQuery1.sql">
          <AssociatedConnectionMoniker>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:hostname\instancename:True</AssociatedConnectionMoniker>
          <AssociatedConnSrvName>hostname\instancename</AssociatedConnSrvName>
          <AssociatedConnUserName />
          <FullPath>SQLQuery1.sql</FullPath>
        </FileNode>
```